# PHPUnit - Trying to @cover not existing method

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

My test case looks like this:

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /** @covers MyClass::bar */
    function testBar()
    {
        $result = MyClass::bar();
        $this->assertSomething($result);
    }

}
```

Now, the test itself works perfectly fine but code coverage complains with:

```
PHP_CodeCoverage_Exception: Trying to @cover not existing method "MyClass::bar *//**".
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Correction

The issue was not within PHPUnit its self but withing PHP_CodeCoverage. The parsing logic is somewhat duplicated there and the PHPUnit fix (see below) didn't help in that case.

The patch to fix this for 3.6 is:

```diff
diff --git a/PHP/CodeCoverage/Util.php b/PHP/CodeCoverage/Util.php
index f90220d..54ce44b 100644
--- a/PHP/CodeCoverage/Util.php
+++ b/PHP/CodeCoverage/Util.php
@@ -196,12 +196,12 @@ class PHP_CodeCoverage_Util
         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
             return array();
         }
-        $docComment = $class->getDocComment() . $method->getDocComment();
+        $docComment = substr($class->getDocComment(), 3, -2) . PHP_EOL . substr($method->getDocComment(), 3, -2);
 
         foreach (self::$templateMethods as $templateMethod) {
             if ($class->hasMethod($templateMethod)) {
                 $reflector   = $class->getMethod($templateMethod);
-                $docComment .= $reflector->getDocComment();
+                $docComment .= substr($reflector->getDocComment(), 3, -2);
                 unset($reflector);
             }
         }
```

I've opened a ticket for this at [**`https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/121`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/121).

Until this fix is released (and chances are that only happens for PHPUnit 3.7) you need to use the three liner.

---

### Old Answer:

#### Old versions of PHPUnit didn't work with one line annotations.

PHPUnit tried to find a class/method combination named: `"MyClass::bar *//**"`

#### Using a three line annotation works with all versions

```
/** 
 * @covers MyClass::bar 
 */
```

I fixed this **`PHPUnit 3.6.4`**.

See [**`Issue 328`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/328).

From `PHPUnit >= 3.6.4` your code should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using `PHPUnit 3.6.12` so shouldn't it work? Curiously, using a three line annotation *does* work. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it is appending the beginning of the docblock to the end. Perhaps it works if the end of the comment is on the same line as long as the annotation isn't on the starting line as well.

Comment: The doc block is taken from `ReflectionClass->getDocComment();` but yeah. The test is failing. I look into it. This is especially strange as there is a test case for this withing phpunit

Comment: Bug is fixed and will be released with PHPUnit 3.7.2 / PHP_CodeCoverage 1.2.3

Answer (score 4):

Another reason (which was the reason in my case) is not using the *complete* classname including the namespace.

```
// Should be like
@covers \Vendor\Module\MyClass::doSomething
```

Comment: yep this was definitely my case. there's an open pull request for that though https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/1312

Comment: apparently still an issue, this resolved recognition for me in phpunit 8.4.0 testing against a php 7.2.23 project using an autoloader